# Laravel Auth Scaffolding view styling is missing

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I run `php artisan make:auth` command in laravel 5.3, it generates the scaffolding for me but the view styles are missing.

Login and registered views are not styles, they are just simple html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double check source code if the styles links are linked correctly or not ?

Check views code and  in there check for the link and script tags . You should use something like this to link the css and scripts etc

`{{ url('styles.css') }}` It will grab the styles from your app public directory.

Answer (score 0):

In your project_name\resources\views\layouts\app.blade.php view file, just remove first slash in css path - instead of:

```
<link href="/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

put:

```
<link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

You will probably need to do the same for js path.

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install

npm run dev
```

Once the dependencies have been installed using npm install, you can compile your SASS files to plain CSS using Laravel Mix. The npm run dev command will process the instructions in your webpack.mix.js file. Typically, your compiled CSS will be placed in the public/css directory:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/frontend#writing-css

Answer (score 0):

You need load file .css and .js

1) execute in your project

```
 npm install
```

2) then execute
    `npm run dev` => now in folder /public **now exist folder js and css**

3) reload page